# I want to make the about page php

Tags: php

I have the following code, but when I go to the location `localhost/index.php?id=gentritabazi/about`, redirect me to welcome. What could be the issue?

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '') {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $_GET['id']);
    if(NumRows('users', 'username', $id)) {
        redirect('welcome');
    } else {
        $page = 'profile';
        include($Root_Directory. 'inc/profile.php');
        include('layout'. $layout. '/profile.php');

        if($_GET['id'] == "{$id}/about") {
            include('layout'. $layout. '/profile_about.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: value of $id from db ?

Comment: Can you share us the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate strings

```
 if($_GET['id'] == $id.'/about')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate string like

```
if($_GET['id'] == "$id/about")
```

**OR**

```
if($_GET['id'] == $id .'/about')
```

Comment: Your first is wrong because you set space `"$id /about"` and make this string wrong. It should be `"{$id}/about"`